# Bluetooth not working on Asus X555LN (14.10)

Tags: 14.10, bluetooth, asus

I need help with my notebook Asus X555LN, the bluetooth adapter doesn't seem to exist to Ubuntu. On Windows it works fine, but on Ubuntu 14.10 it doesn't. I've istalled blueman and still my bluetooth doesn't work.

Here is the result from lsusb

```
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
   Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb | grep Bluetooth doesn't show an output. dmesg | grep -i blue outputs this

```
    [   15.345862] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
    [   15.345882] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [   15.345889] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [   15.345892] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [   15.345901] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   15.350356] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [   15.350367] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [   15.350372] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [   15.479263] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   15.479266] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   15.479274] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

rfkill list shows this:

```
    0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

and here is the lpsci result:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
    00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 0b)
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
    00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
    00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
    00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
    00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
    00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device isn't supported yet in the Ubuntu kernel, but that isn't a problem

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbmm9vfg2fby2zn/fw-04ca_2006.hcd
sudo cp fw-04ca_2006.hcd /lib/firmware
sudo cp fw-04ca_2006.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd

wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnlvxmw5l7mwn2d/bluetooth.tar.gz
tar -zxvf bluetooth.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

You might have to reboot and it should work for the current kernel.  If you do updates and your bluetooth quits working again after a reboot, you may have updated the kernel, then do the following

```
cd ~/bluetooth
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

EDIT: Since it appears there might be an issue with xhci

```
echo "blacklist btusb | sudo tee /etc/modprobe./btusb.conf

gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Then add two lines above `exit 0` so the last three lines are

```
sleep 40
modprobe btusb
exit 0
```

save, exit and reboot

Comment: My computer recognizes the Bluetooth now. But other bluetooth devices can't be seen from my pc and viceversa.

After I restart my pc, the bluetooth goes back to being nonexistant to my pc and after i run the "sudo modprobe btusb" command it gets recognized.

I've tried the same commands that i've posted and everyone got the same result as before, except "dmesg | grep -i blue
" that outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/JCQmgDUz).

Comment: Also rfkill adds this lines at the end.

4: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: `sudo cp /lib/firmware/fw-04ca_2006.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd` and you should be set.  If btusb doesn't load on its own `echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`  Reboot

Comment: It was working perfectly, but after a day it stopped working again. I've used all the commands you said but nothing happened. "dmesg | grep -i blue " outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/tWMNwXax) now.

Comment: Do a complete shutdown instead of reboots and see if it happens, likely a bug still in the code

Comment: I did a complete shoutdown and the bluetooth didn't work. The output of "dmesg | grep -i blue" was the same as before. After that i used the "sudo modprobe -r btusb" and "sudo modprobe btusb" commands and it worked.

Comment: If you did the echo btusb command, we should probably edit and remove btusb `gksudo gedit /etc/modules` and delete only btusb, save, exit and reboot

Comment: I did that and the bluetooth didn't work. When I run "sudo modprobe btusb" it starts again

Comment: It might be the same issue with xhci_hcd that Atheros bluetooth, I will edit answer with solution

Comment: sorry jeremy31, but can you upload a link to "bluetooth.tar.gz", i had to format my pc and i cant fix the bluetooth via this method

Comment: I think asking a new question would be preferred as Ubuntu 14.10 is no longer supported